# Template doesn't exist on heroku, but does locally

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-templates

So I tested my project locally, and everything seems to work perfectly.

Although, when I pushed my project to my heroku server, everything except for one link didn't seem to work. When requesting the page, I got an TemplateDoesNotExist at /locations/add/ error. Once again, this page works locally, so how can it be that the page doesn't exist?

Here is the urls.py snippet:

```
    urlpatterns = patterns(
        '',

        url(r'^add/$', login_required(AddLocation.as_view()), name="add_location"),
)
```

the view:

```
class AddLocation(View):

    template_name = "dash/Addlocation.html"
    form = locationForm()
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
        self.form.fields['existing_regions'].queryset = Region.objects.filter(location__manager=user)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': self.form})
```

and the full traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  87.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/app/pinpoint/apps/locationmanager/views.py" in get
  39.         return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': self.form})
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render
  53.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  162.         t = get_template(template_name)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
  138.     template, origin = find_template(template_name)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in find_template
  131.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /locations/add/
Exception Value: dash/Addlocation.html
```

Here are my template dirs:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../templates'),
)
```

and here is my installed apps as requested:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.formtools',
    #'rest_framework',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    #'pinpoint.apps.careers',
    #'pinpoint.apps.contact',
    'pinpoint.profile',
    'south',
    'pinpoint.apps.beaconmanager',
    'pinpoint.apps.api',
    'pinpoint.apps.geofencemanager',
    'pinpoint.apps.locationmanager',
    'pinpoint.apps.messagemanager',
    'django_extensions',



)
```

my  template loaders:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)
```

I can provide more details if needed. Anyone know why this link doesn't exist on heroku but does locally?

Comment: Show also your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` and `INSTALLED_APPS` settings.

Comment: I have added both, and also included my loaders. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have realized what was wrong.

Two things:

1. The urls.py for my app needed `django.core.urlresolvers import reverse`
2. The `template_name = "dash/Addlocation.html"` needed to be changed to `template_name = "dash/AddLocation.html"`

Thanks to those that pointed me in the right direction.